# Difference between Ubuntu software and Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, deb

I've downloaded `.deb` extension installation file for `brackets` from `www.brackets.io`. But I am unable to install it by using `ubuntu software center` or `ubuntu software` applications. Even though I have no idea about potential difference of these two, they both list applications for ubuntu. And the former is far from responsive. All that it is able to show is the first page with big banner of either `blender` or `inkscape`.

Could someone explain to me the difference and why these softwares are far from being responsive and find me a way to install the `bracket` software.

Thanks.

Comment: Try install .deb package in terminal. Type `sudo dpkg -i package.deb`.

Comment: What  BlueManCZ meant You would need to run this command from terminal application, from Downloads directory. If You are not familiar with terminal, You could drag&drop this downloaded file on software-center, which should prompt to install it.

Comment: Dependency issue arise...like `Package libgcrypt11 is not installed`

Comment: @ShafkathullahIhsan It's a known issue yet to be solved. I suggest reading the following discussion (and following the links) for a workaround: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12380

Comment: @CelticWarrior link was helpful